# Average of dynamic row range

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a table of rows which consist of zeros and numbers like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
0   0   0   4   3   1   0   1   0   2   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   1   4   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
9   5   7   9   10  7   2   3   6   4   4   0   1   0
```

I want to calculate an average of the numbers including zeros, but starting from the first nonzero value and put it into column after tables end. E.g. for the first row first value is 4, so average - 11/11; for the second - 7/13; the last one is 67/14.

How could I using excel formulas do this? Probably `OFFSET` with nested `IF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still needs to be entered as an array formula (ctrl-shift-enter) but it isn't volatile:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(($A2:$O2),MATCH(TRUE,$A2:$O2<>0,0)):$O2)
```

or, depending on location:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(($A2:$O2);MATCH(TRUE;$A2:$O2<>0;0)):$O2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about array formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is the same no matter how many 0's you include, so all you need to worry about is what to divide it by, which you could determine using nested `IF`s, or take a cue from this: https://superuser.com/questions/671435/excel-formula-to-get-first-non-zero-value-in-row-and-return-column-header

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Scott Hunter, for good reference.
I solved the problem using a huge formula, and I think it's a bit awkward.
Here it is:
`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(A2:O2;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(A2:O2<>0;;);0)));TRUE):O2)`